# What is a single word for the things that can be heard from a particular place?

Tags: single-word-requests

A *view* is the things that can be seen from a particular place. What's the auditory equivalent? Shorter words preferred.

Comment: "ambient sound" might fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simple and short preference is for "[sounds](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sounds)" (note definition 5).

> The sounds of the city outside could be heard through the paper-thin
>   walls.

or

> Walking through the forest, one can experience the sounds of nature.

There are also more famous examples: [Sounds of Silence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sounds_of_Silence), [Sounds of Then](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sounds_of_Then). Googling "sounds of" or "sounds from" will bring many many examples which may fit your desired use.

Answer (score 0):

Would acoustics work for your purposes?

If you played a recording in two different locations, while the sound would be the same in both locations, what you would hear in each location would be different, because of the acoustics of that specific location.

" the qualities of a room (such as its shape or size) that make it easy or difficult for people inside to hear sounds clearly : acoustic qualities" - http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acoustics

Comment: A good answer will have explanations/examples/sources. Could you explain why you think "acoustics" is a good choice?

Comment: explanations, examples and sources added :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "soundscape"? The sounds heard in a particular location, considered as a whole.

"I've always loved the soundscape of a forest at dusk"